# Help seeing new vertices, then creating a face with my new curve -> mesh

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, 3d-printing

I am currently following this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYUGMvZsu3w&t=361s and at 46 minutes he demonstrates how he turned his curve into a mesh, then a face. I have my curve, but once turned into a mesh, I cannot find any of the vertices to create a face!
Here is what my curve looked like before the mesh conversion:
[image]

Then when converted into a mesh:
[image]

From here, I can't seem to add vertices, or select it really to create a face to build off of. Any help is very much appreciated! Please and thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in face select mode, so vertices and edges are not as clear.  Switch to vertex select mode if you want better vertex visibility.  If you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking you can select multiple modes.

[image]

Comment: OMG thank you so much! I knew it would be something simple like that! Thank you!

Comment: Done! Thanks again!